# Create dataframes from main dataframe dynamically

Tags: python

I have the following dataframe:

|  | country | player_name | initial_time | initial_reason | initial_position | ending_time | ending_reason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Switzerland | Granit Xhaka | 00:00 | Starting XI | Left Defensive Midfield |  | Final Whistle |
| 47 | Turkey | İrfan Can Kahveci | 00:00 | Starting XI | Left Center Midfield | 45:00 | Tactical Shift |
| 43 | Turkey | Merih Demiral | 00:00 | Starting XI | Right Center Back |  | Final Whistle |
| 35 | Turkey | Kaan Ayhan | 00:00 | Starting XI | Center Defensive Midfield | 45:00 | Tactical Shift |
| 32 | Turkey | Ozan Tufan | 00:00 | Starting XI | Right Center Midfield | 45:00 | Tactical Shift |
| 29 | Turkey | Burak Yılmaz | 00:00 | Starting XI | Center Forward | 45:00 | Tactical Shift |
| 28 | Turkey | Mert Müldür | 00:00 | Starting XI | Left Back |  | Final Whistle |
| 27 | Turkey | Mehmet Zeki Çelik | 00:00 | Starting XI | Right Back |  | Final Whistle |
| 26 | Turkey | Caglar Söyüncü | 00:00 | Starting XI | Left Center Back |  | Final Whistle |
| 20 | Turkey | Hakan Çalhanoğlu | 00:00 | Starting XI | Left Midfield | 45:00 | Tactical Shift |
| 16 | Turkey | Cengiz Ünder | 00:00 | Starting XI | Right Midfield | 45:00 | Tactical Shift |
| 12 | Switzerland | Nico Elvedi | 00:00 | Starting XI | Right Center Back |  | Final Whistle |
| 51 | Turkey | Uğurcan Çakır | 00:00 | Starting XI | Goalkeeper |  | Final Whistle |
| 4 | Switzerland | Breel-Donald Embolo | 00:00 | Starting XI | Left Center Forward | 85:03 | Substitution - Off (Tactical) |
| 2 | Switzerland | Haris Seferović | 00:00 | Starting XI | Right Center Forward | 74:38 | Substitution - Off (Tactical) |
| 1 | Switzerland | Xherdan Shaqiri | 00:00 | Starting XI | Center Attacking Midfield | 75:00 | Substitution - Off (Tactical) |
| 3 | Switzerland | Ricardo Iván Rodríguez Araya | 00:00 | Starting XI | Left Center Back |  | Final Whistle |
| 6 | Switzerland | Manuel Obafemi Akanji | 00:00 | Starting XI | Center Back |  | Final Whistle |
| 7 | Switzerland | Yann Sommer | 00:00 | Starting XI | Goalkeeper |  | Final Whistle |
| 9 | Switzerland | Remo Freuler | 00:00 | Starting XI | Right Defensive Midfield |  | Final Whistle |
| 5 | Switzerland | Steven Zuber | 00:00 | Starting XI | Left Wing Back | 84:44 | Substitution - Off (Tactical) |
| 10 | Switzerland | Silvan Widmer | 00:00 | Starting XI | Right Wing Back | 91:12 | Substitution - Off (Tactical) |
| 21 | Turkey | Hakan Çalhanoğlu | 45:00 | Tactical Shift | Right Attacking Midfield | 53:59 | Tactical Shift |
| 36 | Turkey | Kaan Ayhan | 45:00 | Tactical Shift | Left Defensive Midfield | 53:59 | Tactical Shift |
| 48 | Turkey | İrfan Can Kahveci | 45:00 | Tactical Shift | Left Attacking Midfield | 53:59 | Tactical Shift |
| 30 | Turkey | Burak Yılmaz | 45:00 | Tactical Shift | Right Center Forward | 53:59 | Tactical Shift |
| 17 | Turkey | Cengiz Ünder | 45:00 | Tactical Shift | Left Center Forward | 53:59 | Tactical Shift |
| 33 | Turkey | Ozan Tufan | 45:00 | Tactical Shift | Right Defensive Midfield | 53:59 | Tactical Shift |
| 22 | Turkey | Hakan Çalhanoğlu | 53:59 | Tactical Shift | Left Midfield | 71:05 | Tactical Shift |
| 49 | Turkey | İrfan Can Kahveci | 53:59 | Tactical Shift | Right Center Midfield | 71:05 | Tactical Shift |
| 31 | Turkey | Burak Yılmaz | 53:59 | Tactical Shift | Center Forward |  | Final Whistle |
| 34 | Turkey | Ozan Tufan | 53:59 | Tactical Shift | Left Center Midfield | 62:33 | Substitution - Off (Tactical) |
| 37 | Turkey | Kaan Ayhan | 53:59 | Tactical Shift | Center Defensive Midfield | 62:30 | Substitution - Off (Tactical) |
| 18 | Turkey | Cengiz Ünder | 53:59 | Tactical Shift | Right Midfield | 71:05 | Tactical Shift |
| 38 | Turkey | Okay Yokuşlu | 62:30 | Substitution - On (Tactical) | Center Defensive Midfield | 71:05 | Tactical Shift |
| 44 | Turkey | Yusuf Yazıcı | 62:33 | Substitution - On (Tactical) | Left Center Midfield | 71:05 | Tactical Shift |
| 39 | Turkey | Okay Yokuşlu | 71:05 | Tactical Shift | Right Defensive Midfield |  | Final Whistle |
| 45 | Turkey | Yusuf Yazıcı | 71:05 | Tactical Shift | Center Attacking Midfield | 79:41 | Tactical Shift |
| 19 | Turkey | Cengiz Ünder | 71:05 | Tactical Shift | Right Wing | 79:40 | Substitution - Off (Tactical) |
| 50 | Turkey | İrfan Can Kahveci | 71:05 | Tactical Shift | Left Wing | 79:40 | Substitution - Off (Tactical) |
| 23 | Turkey | Hakan Çalhanoğlu | 71:05 | Tactical Shift | Left Defensive Midfield | 85:11 | Substitution - Off (Tactical) |
| 8 | Switzerland | Mario Gavranović | 74:38 | Substitution - On (Tactical) | Right Center Forward |  | Final Whistle |
| 15 | Switzerland | Ruben Vargas | 75:00 | Substitution - On (Tactical) | Center Attacking Midfield |  | Final Whistle |
| 24 | Turkey | Kenan Karaman | 79:40 | Substitution - On (Tactical) | Right Wing | 79:41 | Tactical Shift |
| 41 | Turkey | Orkun Kökçü | 79:40 | Substitution - On (Tactical) | Left Wing | 79:41 | Tactical Shift |
| 46 | Turkey | Yusuf Yazıcı | 79:41 | Tactical Shift | Right Wing |  | Final Whistle |
| 25 | Turkey | Kenan Karaman | 79:41 | Tactical Shift | Left Wing |  | Final Whistle |
| 42 | Turkey | Orkun Kökçü | 79:41 | Tactical Shift | Center Attacking Midfield |  | Final Whistle |
| 13 | Switzerland | Loris Benito | 84:44 | Substitution - On (Tactical) | Left Wing Back |  | Final Whistle |
| 11 | Switzerland | Admir Mehmedi | 85:03 | Substitution - On (Tactical) | Left Center Forward |  | Final Whistle |
| 40 | Turkey | Dorukhan Toköz | 85:11 | Substitution - On (Tactical) | Left Defensive Midfield |  | Final Whistle |
| 14 | Switzerland | Kevin Mbabu | 91:12 | Substitution - On (Tactical) | Right Wing Back |  | Final Whistle |

I am hoping to create a data frame that contains all `country`, `player_name`, `initial_position` that are on the field for EACH substitution time.

So, at 'initial_time' = 45:00.. I want to know which players are on the field for Switzerland and Turkey.

```
dfs = {f'df_{n}': df[df['initial_time'] == n] for n in df['initial_time'].unique()}
```

This code produces a data frame for each substitution time and the players that were subbed in at that time, but it fails to include the players that were already in the game prior that are not being subbed out/subbed in.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: `df['initial_time'] <= n`?

Answer (score 0):

In your last paragraph you nicely describe which logical factors create the desired dataframe. The only task remaining is to translate that to logical filters for pandas:

```
dfs = {f'df_{n}': df[
    (df['initial_time'] <= n) & (  # player has entered game at or before this time AND
            (df['ending_time'] > n) |  # player has not yet left game OR
            (df['ending_time'] == "")  # player never leaves game
    )] for n in df['initial_time'].unique()}
```